# Counting arrays in D3 and getting that number to visualise map points

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, topojson, cartography

I am making cartographic visualisation in D3 with topoJson. I have visualised cities as points with a given radius. However, I want to see this attribute based on how many values I have there (let's say kindergartens in each city) - that is for Glasgow 57, Dundee 26.

[image]

So I just need to count how many arrays are there in the values. I have searched but have not found any suitable solution.

```
        enterSelection
           .append("circle")
           .attr("r", 4);
```

EDIT: Need to update the 4 in the code below. If I am using tip given in comments, it gives me only the radius in the size of the array of the specific city (but I need different radius for each city)
Tried to change attribute to

```
.attr("r", d=>(d.town.values.length))
```

but that gives me *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined* error

Comment: try cities[1].values.length

Comment: @TilakMaddy I am using it in the code when I am setting up the radius of each point in here:   enterSelection
   .append("circle")
   .attr("r", towns[1].values.length); (added to the question)
but then I get only the radius of specific city.

Comment: @TilakMaddy When I am using the console, it works when typing towns.map(d => d.values.length

Comment: @TilakMaddy I found out (viz. solution) but thanks for pointing me at the direction

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution that worked.

```
enterSelection
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", d => d.values.length)
```